# How are virtual and override functions called in multilevel inheritance c#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I know how virtual and overridden methods are called but I only understand one level of inheritance.  What is the output of the following program and how does the compiler work with multilevel inheritance?

```
public class Parent
    {
        public virtual void Method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parent Method");
        }
    }

    public class Child : Parent
    {
        public virtual void Method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Child Method");
        }
    }

    public class Child1 : Child
    {
        public override void Method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Child1 Method");
        }
    }

    public class Child2 : Child1
    {
        public override void Method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Child2 Method");
        }
    }

 public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Parent p1 = new Child();
            p1.Method();
            Parent p2 = new Child1();
            p2.Method();
            Parent p3 = new Child2();
            p3.Method();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be *public **override** void Method()* in `Child` class?

Comment: The C# compiler generates a warning on this code, one you should not ignore.  Intentionally hiding a base class method is almost never not a mistake.  There is just no point using the same name for Child.Method.  Just name it something else and it will be instantly obvious what happens at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to understand if you follow this simple logic.

```
Parent p3 = new Child2();
```

`p3` available structure will be of `Parent` type, while the concrete implementation methods that are being **overridden** to use the actual object `Child2`.

This is because the object we actually using is `new Child2()`